# Do crew bonuses stack?

Tags: payday-2

There are some skills in the game that offer bonuses to the whole crew such as *Fast Learner* in the Mastermind tree.

If multiple members in the game use the same crew bonus, do the effects stack?

Comment: is this question limited to PC only?

Comment: @ColeBusby Not really, unless it's a PC specific feature. I don't personally own a console so I don't know how the console versions are.

Comment: Consoles are on the equivalent of Update 1. I can do some tests tonight but the results are going to be inconclusive for PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** - crew bonuses do not stack - at all. In the instance two or more of your crew members have an ability that provides a crew bonus, these do not stack. However, there are a few caveats;

- **Fast Learner** (ace) provides a crew experience bonus, this is separate from **Fast Learner** (not ace) which provides a personal experience bonus. These two bonuses are separate bonuses, meaning if every member of your crew has one point in Fast Learner and one of your crew members has it aced, every crew member will receive a double experience bonus (a personal bonus from having one point in Fast Learner, and a crew bonus from the crew member that has it aced). If two or more crew members have Fast Learner aced, this bonus does not stack.
- **Endurance** (ace) provides a crew stamina bonus, this is separate from **Endurance** (not ace) which provides a personal stamina bonus. This works in the same way as **Fast Learner**.
- Abilities like **Leadership** (both ace and not aced) which provide crew bonuses at both levels do not stack. If multiple members of your crew have one of these abilities there is no additional bonus provided to the crew (they will, in the instance of Leadership, receive a 25% bonus for the first tier or a 50% bonus for aced Leadership)

This means, if you're building up a crew that is going to run heists together constantly, you'll want to avoid doubling up on abilities like **Leadership** but may want to each expend a point in abilities like **Endurance** or **Fast Learner**.

Comment: Please provide a credible/official source if you are interested in the bounty. Getting a sourced answer was the goal of the bounty

Comment: Since there is no official announcement, you won't get an answer backed by Overkill at this time. All of my Payday 2 answers are based on extensive testing and drawing upon the numbers in [Payday 2 - The Numbers](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=169443444) and [PD2Skills](http://www.pd2skills.info/) - I am merely posted what I've tested, regardless of the bounty.

Comment: OK, unless someone provides another source soon I will go with this answer, PD2skills looks like an acceptable source

Answer (score 6):

[From a steam discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864977025794855224/):

> Crew bonuses don't stack. You can only have 1 of each different bonus
>   name. Ace and Basic Fast Learner do stack because they have different
>   names.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no evidence provided by this, just what an unknown individual suggested.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, because it doesnt seem to be an authoritative answer... I dont know how to handle that.

Comment: @hobs good question. If you want a more authoritative answer, you can start a bounty on this question with a request for a better answer. That will move the question to the bounty area ensuring it gets plenty of exposure and will probably get a better answer. Since i'm not sure you can use starting 100 rep for bounties, I can do it for you

Comment: @hobs and Lawton, with every [iteration (read update)](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976114833820323/) of the game, this varies to promote fair and balanced gameplay. It's going to be a case-by-case basis thus making it difficult to narrow down. If you both wish to try to find out, equip the skills in question and make test cases. Ukrainian Job is great place to test this as it has one job, appears often and is relatively simple. I have the Console version so I'm behind 13 updates. However, the latest update has re-written the entire skill set so keep that in mind.

Comment: @cole The fact that they are updating the game does not mean that they are frequently changing whether or not these types of abilities stack, and I see nothing in the patch notes either way. If you are saying that they have been frequently changing this between patches then please provide evidence. The fact that it is POSSIBLE for them to change it is irrelevant.

Comment: @ColeBusby update 13 did not "re-write the whole skill tree" - it merely changed the descriptions of each skill to include the numbers as per [pd2skills.com](http://pd2skills.com) (They even get a shout out in the patch notes...)

Comment: @lawton thanks for the offer, but its not that important imo. Keep the karma :D