# Do Skill Tree skills stack?

Tags: payday-2

Example:

1. Sharpshooter (Aced) - 25% Decrease to assault weapon recoil
2. Leadership (Aced) - 50% Decrease to all weapon recoil
3. The Professional - 50% Decrease recoil to all silent weapons

So does leadership affect only unsilenced weapons, and or do all of these stack?
All of these are from different skill trees.

Another example:

1. The Professional (Aced) - 50% increase in accuracy, 2x iron sights
2. Rifleman - 2x multiplier to assault rifle zoom

Would these stack as well?

Comment: -125% recoil to silenced assault rifles!

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Bonuses like the ones you've mentioned, i.e. Leadership, Sharpshooter, etc. Stack if they pertain to you. If they are crew bonuses, i.e. Two members of the crew both have leadership aced they only receive 50% not 100% from that. (See more [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127443/do-crew-bonuses-stack))

If the buff is simply directed towards you then they will stack. So **simply put** yes Sharpshooter will stack with leadership and The Professional.

However, I do not know whether the bonuses are cumulative or multiplicative. (I'd assume the first but I'm not certain).